# geting error while downloading libxp6 for ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu-20.04, lib

I tried to downlod libxp.so.6 for ubuntu 20.04 using the command "$  wget ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libx/libxp/libxp6_1.0.2-2_amd64.deb"

and getting this error
--2023-08-19 14:48:44--  http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libx/libxp/libxp6_1.0.2-2_amd64.deb
Resolving ftp.us.debian.org (ftp.us.debian.org)... 208.80.154.139, 64.50.233.100, 64.50.236.52, ...
Connecting to ftp.us.debian.org (ftp.us.debian.org)|208.80.154.139|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2023-08-19 14:48:45 ERROR 404: Not Found.

Please resolve.

I tried to download it manually but unable to get the repository.

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps someone, I was able to install it using the version given here and following their instructions: [https://launchpad.net/~zeehio/+archive/ubuntu/libxp](https://launchpad.net/%7Ezeehio/+archive/ubuntu/libxp)

I added the PPA to my system with:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:zeehio/libxp
sudo apt update
```

And then installed libxp6 through

```
sudo apt-get install libxp6
```

I am using Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS